# Debian 7, Hyper-v network problems

Tags: networking, debian, hyper-v

I have Debian 7.9 as one of hyper-v guests (on window server 2012R2). This Debian has legacy network adapter on hyper-v settings. I have been pinging Debian host constantly, there is 4-22% packet lost, debending on network load to that host... Same time other hyper-v guests (Debian 8, Windows server 2012R2) have ~0% lost so there should be no hardware problem.

Should I be able to use Network adapter instead of Legacy Adapter on Debian 7 hyper-v? Debian 8 has Network adapter, not Legacy Adapter

I tryed to switch to Network adapter, but it seems to be even worse, 80 % packet lost...

I may have missed something, but what?

**I tryed  Hyper-V switch mode change from dynamic to Hyper-V. Now this change seems to help on dropping problem. Drop rate near 0% thought Debian7 lost rate is the higest on my Hyper-V host...**

Comment: According to Microsoft, both the 7.x and 8.x version of Debian are supported on Hyper-V and have the LIS packages preinstalled on them. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/compute/hyper-v/supported-debian-virtual-machines-on-hyper-v, this means that they both should work the same way, how are the host network cards are configured? any special configuration on the guest VMs network cards?

Comment: How do I inspect how network cards are configured on hosts?

Comment: Both Debian 7 and 8 have 00:0a.0 Ethernet controller: Digital Equipment Corporation DECchip 21140 [FasterNet] (rev 20)

Comment: Here is an excellent checklist that have so many options to go over, pay attention to the checklist for the networking part: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2013/03/10/windows-server-2012-hyper-v-best-practices-in-easy-checklist-form/

Comment: Yes, everthing should be ok. There massive difference between packet lost on hyper-v guest Debian 7, Debian 8. The debian 7 has couple of low trafic web sites on...  There are some packet loses on Server 2012 quests too, but lost rate is normally < 1 % rate. could this indicate some other network problem or what should I do...

Comment: Is all of this happening on a LAN or WAN over internet? if inside a LAN, you definitely need to check all the physical components in between your test device and the physical server, network cards, cables, switches, routers, you shouldn't get any packet drop at all. If WAN is involved this is a different story and is expected the least to say, you should test with a device next to the physical server.

Comment: Happening on LAN. On same LAN I have othe physhical servers. Ping lost rate on other than hyper-v guest are 0 or near 0 losts. Our other Hyper-v quests are dropping less than 1 %, but this Debian 7 is dropping 4 to 22 % of packets. Packets are dropped inside virtual switch too, ping from hyper-v quest to another...

Comment: This is going no where, You should try to isolate the problem and then focus on solving it, I'd suggest things like 1) move the VM to another host 2) try another install of the same VM guest 3) Check that you have the latest updates of the LIS module and Linux in general. Once you isolate the problem it'll be easier for you to figure out a solution.